# How do I format the datetime in coreui datatable react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, datatable, core-ui

I am supposed to format the date time to display "28 Sep 2020 00:11".

my initial value is this "2020-09-28 00:11:50".

currently, this is how it is being displayed.

[image]

i am using coreui's datatable.

this is my code for the datatable assigning.

[image]

I want to know if there's any way i can format the datetime here?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @zahrazamani how do you apply the moment code in this datatable?

Comment: I'm not sure I think so ....                                                                                          return items.map(item => {
        return { 
          updateon: moment(item.updateon).format('yyyy:mm:dd')
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
createdAt: (item: any) => (
    <td>
        <Moment format="DD.MM.YYYY">{item.createdAt}</Moment>
    </td>
)
```

Datatable has scoppedSlots prop for change any scop, I used react-moment for date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Detail I implement with good anwers @Kelvin Schoofs,@calal_mnf:

```js
scopedSlots = {{
                'createdAt':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss">{item.createdAt}</Moment>
                    </td>
                  )
              }}
```

and

import Moment from 'react-moment';

This work for me !
Hope it useful for you